# building glibc-2.25 error : FAIL: nptl/tst-cond17

Tags: linux, gnu-make, glibc, test-suite, linux-from-scratch

I've been reading through **LFS** while following the instructions till I got to the point where I needed to compile `glibc-2.25` for the actual system.

After running `make check`, have encountered the following failures:

```
FAIL: nptl/tst-cond17
FAIL: posix/tst-getaddrinfo4
FAIL: posix/tst-getaddrinfo5
Summary of test results:
      3 FAIL
   2640 PASS
     26 UNSUPPORTED
     43 XFAIL
      2 XPASS
make[1]: *** [Makefile:355: tests] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.25'
make: *** [Makefile:9: check] Error 2
```

Both `posix/tst-getaddrinfo4` and `posix/tst-getaddrinfo5` failures should pose no real threat as indicated by **LFS**, but I am not sure about the first failure `nptl/tst-cond17`.
I have checked the source file and found out that all it does is defining some sort of variable. Here's the code.

```
#define UNLOCK_AFTER_BROADCAST 1
#include "tst-cond16.c"
```

Is it not critical to the build process? or should I try to fix it somehow?

EDIT:

The files `nptl/tst-cond17.o`, `nptl/tst-cond17.o.d` and `nptl/tst-cond17.out` are empty, while the contents of the file `nptl/tst-cond17.test-result` are:

```
FAIL: nptl/tst-cond17
original exit status 127
```

Comment: What's the contents of `nptl/tst-cond17.out` in the build directory? The test harness should log some information in this file.

Comment: Nothing, it's empty.

Comment: Does the failure reproduce if you run `bash testrun.sh nptl/tst-cond17; echo $?` from the build directory? Does that report exit status 127, too?

Comment: Yes, it does, this was the full output: `nptl/tst-cond17: error while loading shared libraries: nptl/tst-cond17: file too short`  `127`

Comment: Oh, that looks like a build problem. What's the size of the file?

Comment: Apparently, it was. After a clean build the fail did not appear. The previous build was interrupted by my laptop's dead battery, maybe this was the reason. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it's not a spurious failure! We already have too many of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked our records, and `tst-cond17` is not generally known to generate spurious failures (or as being affected by unfixed kernel bugs).  I found a reference to a `tst-cond17` failure in the [glibc 2.20 release notes](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Release/2.20), but the submitter comments that, ‘The NPTL failures not mentioned as architecture-independent are thought to result from general unreliability of the board being used for testing.’, so I assume that this does not count.

I would say the `tst-cond17` failure is worth investigating further, especially if you can reproduce it.

Comment: I will start rebuilding glibc and see if I could find anything.

Comment: Error was not reproducable after the rebuild.